# /bin/test prints 'Directory isn't within a workspace: /Users/myusr' in red. Is this an error?

Tags: bash, macos, unix, darwin

After installing ocaml and opam, it has added this line to my `.bash_profile` (macOS).

```sh
test -r /Users/myusr/.opam/opam-init/init.sh && . /Users/myusr/.opam/opam-init/init.sh > /dev/null 2> /dev/null || true
```

That script calls a few more, using the same pattern.

Each call to this `test` binary, located at `/bin/test` prints (in red):

```
Directory isn't within a workspace: '/Users/myuser'
```

Is this an error? What does it mean? Should I remove the call to `test` from all of these script invocations if I don't like seeing red (error-like) messages when I open a terminal?

I can find no information on this.

Comment: I don't think this error comes from `test`, I'd say it comes from `/Users/myusr/.opam/opam-init/init.sh`.

Comment: What happens if you simply run `test -r /Users/myusr/.opam/opam-init/init.sh`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk "Directory isn't within a workspace: '/Users/myuser'"

Comment: OK, post output of `type -a test` and `bash -c 'test -r /Users/myusr/.opam/opam-init/init.sh'`. It's possible that `type` was somehow overwritten but I don't if it's possible to overwrite built-ins.

Comment: Ah, `type -a test` revealed that I (or my company) had aliased test to something like `my-companys-build-system test`. Oops, no wonder no one else had this issue.

Comment: Do you remember how this happened? I hate when some installers add some stuff to my `~/.bashrc`. Anyway, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I probably did it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, after running `type -a test` OP has
realized that something has overwritten `test` command on their machine,
hence the unusual behavior of `test`. Normally, `type -a test` should return something like this:

```
test is a shell builtin
test is /usr/bin/test
test is /bin/test
```

But it's possible to modify `test` by aliasing it or converting it to a
function:

```
$ alias test='echo fake test'
$ type -a test
test is aliased to `echo fake test'
test is a shell builtin
test is /usr/bin/test
test is /bin/test
$ test
fake test
```